# Trac Repository synchronization

Tags: svn, synchronization, repository, trac

I just updated the trac from 0.11 to 0.12 because the multi repository browsing. Before the svn synchronization worked automatically, but now I have to the admin panel and type the `repository resync *` command, is there any way to do this automatically?

Comment: Chances are this is a one-time thing after the update. Or do you need to do this all the time now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read [TracRepositoryAdmin](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin) and follow the instructions there. Basically, you have two options:

- Either you keep the automatic sync on every request, which becomes a performance hog pretty quickly if you have multiple repositories.
- Or you call `trac-admin $ENV changeset added` in the post-commit hook of each repository. This is the preferred option.

Comment: @pylover You can run `trac-admin $ENV repository sync *` from a cron job.